Ubuntu 24.10 has blank login screen layout with missing text when coming back from suspend
When Ubuntu 24.10 comes back from suspend mode, it loses all the letters, and the entire layout of the login and desktop is missing.
GIMP looks with problems to change his window area, the borders won't move, but the size changes after the mouse finishes moving. The GIMP part was happening before I entered suspend mode, but yes, confusing text.
Consider just that 24.10 comes back from suspend mode with its screen showing just a few letters and the layout is blank.

The description seems confusing. For example, it is unclear how you can be seeing Gimp when "the entire layout of the the login and desktop are missed?" Perhaps a clear, readable image of the problem might help. Also, be sure to try basic troubleshooting: Do you logs have any relevant information? Can you reproduce the issue in a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment?

The Gimp part was happening before the I enter the suspend mode, but yes, confuse text. Consider just tat 24.10 coming back of the suspend mode here with his screen showing just few letters and the layout is blank.

Related: 22.04 - How to make resume from suspend work properly on Wayland + Nvidia? &
nvidia - Waking up from suspend makes most things turn black when using Ubuntu 21.10 with Wayland

I have exactly the same problems, seems to be a problem with the (proprietary?) NVIDIA driver and Wayland.
Switching back to X11 (on the login screen) helps and waking up from standby and Gimp work again.

The problem is that Blender is super fast with the Nvidia driver and not much using other options. Thank you for the response.
